# Proving Abel's theorem for elliptic functions

Tags: riemann-surfaces, elliptic-functions

I'm trying to prove the theorem:

**Theorem.** Let $\{z_j\}$ and $\{\zeta_k\}$ be finite sets of distinct points in $M := \mathbb{C}/\langle z \mapsto z + \omega_1, z \mapsto z + \omega_2\rangle$, $n_j$ and $\nu_k$ be positive integers, and $\Lambda$ be the group relative to which we are factoring. Suppose
$$
\sum_j n_j = \sum_k \nu_k
$$
and
$$
\sum_j n_j z_j - \sum_k \nu_k \zeta_k = 0 \qquad \mod{\Lambda}.
$$
Then there exists an elliptic function which has zeros and poles at $\{z_j\}$ and $\{\zeta_k\}$ with the given orders.

*Attempt.* Listing the points $z_j$ and $\zeta_k$ with their respective multiplicities, we obtain sequences $z_j'$ and $\zeta_k'$ of the same length, say $n$. Shifting by a lattice element if needed, we have
$$
\sum_{j = 1}^n z_j' = \sum_{k = 1}^n \zeta_k'.
$$
Define, for $\sigma(z) := z \prod_{\omega \in \Lambda^*} E_2 (z/\omega)$,
$$
f(z) = \prod_{j = 1}^n \frac{\sigma(z - z_j')}{\sigma(z - \zeta_j')}.
$$
This has the desired zeros and poles, but I don't know how to show periodicity.

Comment: Look at equations (4) and (5) here: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/WeierstrassSigmaFunction.html

Comment: I might be blind, but what are $\eta_1$ and $\eta_2$ in those equations?

Comment: Those are constants that one gets by the almost periodicity of the Weierstrass zeta function $\zeta$. If the lattice is $\Lambda:=[2\omega_1, 2\omega_2]$, then $2\eta_j = \zeta(z + 2\omega_j ) − \zeta(z)$